# Compare hex string

Tags: javascript, hex

I am trying to decode a series of hex strings and check some of their nibbles.

In the example below, I am checking string (`hexString`) and checking it if the last 5 bits are set to true (0x1f).  However, it is returning `false`. How can I check a hex string's bits?

```
const hexString = 'f0'

const areFiveLowestBitsSet = (hexString && 0x1f) === 0x1f
console.log(areFiveLowestBitsSet)  // prints true
```

Comment: a string is not a number ... and `&&` is not a bitwise operator, it's a boolean operator - `parseInt(hexString, 16) & 0x1f` is probably what you want

Comment: *"I understand that `hexString` is a string and not really a hex"* The only reason it's "a hex" **is** that it's a string. If it were a number, it would be a number. Hex (or decimal, or octal) are *representations* of numbers in textual form -- e.g., strings. See @Bravo's comment above for what you probably want to do: Parse it, and then check with the bitwise operator.

Comment: *"...and checking it if the last 5 nibbles are set."* Those aren't nibbles. A nibble is four bits. Those are *bits*.

Comment: I'm curious why you keep editing the question, rather than taking and using the information Bravo gave you. This was two typo-level errors (not parsing the string, and using the wrong operator). Since it won't be of use to others in the future, your best bet is just to delete it. Bravo's code does what you've said you want to do.

Comment: @keechan - What do you mean there's no helpful information provided? Bravo's comment above tells you exactly what to do to solve your problem. Also, correcting terminology **is** helpful. Knowing the right terminology helps you look things up, helps you explain things to other people, helps you understand what other people are saying, ...

Comment: ```parseInt(hexString, 16) & 0x1f``` prints ```16```. Not sure how that can help derive whether the bits are actually set. Any tips?

Comment: Yes, the nibble and bits info is helpful -- good to know. But not enough to actually push to close this question.

Comment: @keechan - They were just showing you how to fix the `(hexString && 0x1f)` part, you still need the `==`.

Comment: That's more like it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're not parsing the string to get a number
2. You're using `&&`, which is a logical operator, not the bitwise operator `&`

Parse the number as hex (`parseInt(hexString, 16)`) and use the bitwise operator:

```js
let hexString = 'f0'

let areFiveLowestBitsSet = (parseInt(hexString, 16) & 0x1f) === 0x1f;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−^
console.log(areFiveLowestBitsSet); // false

hexString = '3f';
areFiveLowestBitsSet = (parseInt(hexString, 16) & 0x1f) === 0x1f;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−^
console.log(areFiveLowestBitsSet); // true
```